# Уменьшение расхода АКБ, Android

Tags: java, android, видео, энергосбережение

Есть приложение, которое пишет видео в режиме видеорегистратора (т.е. отрезками по 1-2 мин.). Проблема заключается в высоком расходе заряда. Я понимаю, что запись видео довольно энергозатратный процесс, но всё-таки хотелось узнать - какие есть способы снизить нагрузку на АКБ?

Comment: Писать менее качественное видео, с меньшим FPS, например. Вы вообще пытаетесь получить КПД больше 1 - расходовать энергию, но не расходовать энергию...

Comment: @metalurgus, да, качество видео я уже уменьшил до уровня, которого хватает. Ахах, да, согласен, но даже если не больше 1, то хотя бы 1)))

Comment: Видеорегистратор обычно работает в машине, где есть розетка. А если розетки нет, может не видео писать, а снимать кадры раз в секунду?

Comment: @NickVolynkin гифкорегистратор?)

Comment: @Denis, есть даже стандарт видео такой `MJPEG`, раньше все доступные камеры видеонаблюдения только его и использовали. Как раз потому что меньше ресурсов требует. Автору как вариант попробовать.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MJPEG

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Нужно именно видео и это не авторегистратор, поэтому нет источника питания.